# Worklight server URL settings not visible on an iphone app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have an iOS hybrid app developed in Worklight 6.2.0.1. When I build and deploy it on a device (iOS8.1), the custom Worklight server settings to change the server URL are not visible. The application-descriptor.xml file has the "worklightSettings" set to "true". I cannot delete and re-create the native environment since it has a significant amount of native code and settings. Please suggest a work-around or solution to enable the server settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to "reset" it.

1. Double check the feature is enabled.
2. Then in Xcode, select `Clean` followed by a `Build`.

This typically brings back the Settings.bundle file.

Comment: thank you for this Idan, I had to manually readd my Settings.bundle back through xcode to my project pbxproj after reenabling in the applicationDescriptor.xml